# Laravel insert json type column data to db via model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I'm using a json column in migrations and trying to save values to data via model. Here is my migration,

```php
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->json('title');
    $table->json('message')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And this is my model code,

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Notification extends Model

{
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['title','message'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'title','message'
    ];

},
```

And this is my insert code,

```php
$notification = new Notification();

$notification_title = [
    'en' => 'Request created',
    'it' => 'Richiesta creata',
];
$notification_title = json_encode($notification_title);

$notification_message = [
    'en' => 'Request created',
    'it' => 'Richiesta creata',
];
$notification_message = json_encode($notification_message);

$notification->title = $notification_title;
$notification->message = $notification_message;
$notification->save();
```

Seems like json fields are not saving properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `json_encode()` with [JSON casts](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

```php
class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'title' => 'array',
        'message' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Comment: How does the data get saved?

Comment: Something like this - {"it": "{\"en\":\"Request created\",\"it\":\"Richi...
Sorry but it's hard to copy also :(

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are already applying `json_encode()`. What happens when you leave the casts and remove `$notification_title = json_encode($notification_title);` and `$notification_message = json_encode($notification_message);`?

Comment: Then works fine :) add it as an answer. Thanks so so much

Comment: I've added it to my answer.